# Is there some nifty way to determine if a Hibernate object is "live"?

Tags: hibernate

Given a Hibernate domain object, is there some way I can determine if it is live (i.e. exists in the database) other than searching for it? Is there some method a la `HIbernate.isObjectLive(domainObj)` or `domainObj.amIAlive()` that might be more efficient?

I'm relatively new to Hibernate. If "no" is the answer, I'm ok with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checking its id fields isn't enough? I mean, if it's not live, it usually doesn't have an id...

Comment: I should clarify: I've previously retrieved `domainObj` from the database, so it would have an id.

Comment: So you want to know if the object is still persisted, in a multi-threaded scenario?

Comment: Yes. So if some other thread removed it, I want to be able to check this as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate would only know whether an object is 'live' by that definition by checking the database.  You should use [`Session.get(object.getClass(), object.getId())`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) to see if that's the case.  It'll return null if the object no longer exists in the database.

Be aware that the `Session` has a cache, so if the object is in that cache already, but in the meantime has been deleted from the database, `Session.get(...)` will return a reference.  For this reason you may want to get a new `Session` before doing the check.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way will be:
`select o.id from Entity o where o.id=?`. If this returns empty result, then there is no object there.

Another option (and probably this is preferable in concurrent env)  is to use Optimistic Locking so that the object has a version stored in database and while saving it, it will do something like this: `update Entity set ... where id = ? and version = ?`. It will throw exception if the object is already stale (either updated or removed).

But session.get() will also work, you just need to call session.evict(object) before doing it if the object is expected to be in session level cache.